# Twitter Api To get user data

Tags: django, twitter, django-allauth, django-socialauth

Am using Twitter api for getting all user data and it is working for me via postman.Now i need to write it within a view to fetch all data.So the problem is i used django social auth for registering twitter user and its not saving following data oauth_signature,oauth_timestamp,oauth_nonce.

Url used for twitter api is:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xxxx&count=1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_nonce=xxxx&oauth_timestamp=xxxxxx&oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxx&oauth_token=xxxxxx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=xxxxxx
```

The api url is working in postman and what i need to do is fetch all these data from backend for saving user data.How do i fetch these data,is **django allauth** saving these data?

Comment: what exactly you want ?

Comment: @rajasimon i need to following data oauth_signature,oauth_timestamp,oauth_nonce for sending parameters to the above mentioned url.I need to get users location,language,timezone,country